# How to hide all elements apart from id=mainContainer

Tags: css

I've been trying to hide everything apart from the main content on the following [Facebook post](https://www.facebook.com/thenextweb/posts/10153953291748523)

I've been injecting the following css without luck - can someone please help?

```
html body * {
 display:none;
}

#contentArea {
 display:block;
}
```

Below is a screenshot of what I'm after. [image]

Comment: What is everything? Facebooks header/footer/siderbars? Are you trying to hide "everything" on facebook page?

Comment: Try with visibility rather than display

Comment: That would be piece of cake with some jQuery : $('body > :not(#contentArea)').hide();
                    $('#contentArea').appendTo('body');
                    $('body').css('background', '#fff');

Comment: Can use  display:block !important;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `body *` you are hiding every child.

With `#contentArea` you are showing this block, but still - `body *` persist for child elements AND parent elements.

You have to specify much more rules to hide everything else.

Comment: Thanks, will try that!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before, you cannot display an element which has a parent that was hidden. Anyway, Facebook's layout is simpler than I thought, all you have to do is hide two elements: the header and sidebar. This of course assumes that a user is not logged in.

Inject this CSS

```
#pagelet_bluebar, #rightCol {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Result:

[image: facebook show content only]

Result (user logged in):

[image: facebook show content only - logged in]

To hide the chat sidebar, you can add `#pagelet_sidebar` to the CSS.

```
#pagelet_bluebar, #rightCol, #pagelet_sidebar {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

To conclude: Hide the main parts instead of everything, or use jQuery to target all except your element as suggested by @MaVRoSCy.

Comment: Thanks - I've managed to do that too however; is it possible to hide the grey background too so it's only the main post?

I've been trying that now... including seeing if I can load the mobile version but so far without luck..

Comment: You can disable the background with this: `._5vb_, ._5vb_ #contentCol {background: none !important;}`

Comment: Seems the mobile version has a different header, try this: `._129-,.aclb.apm.abb {display:none;}`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone - the following seems to be the combination of everyone's answers:

```
#leftCol, #pagelet_bluebar, #rightCol, #pagelet_bluebar {
    visibility: hidden !important;
    display: none !important;
}

html ._5vb_.hasLeftCol #contentCol {
    border-left: initial  !important;
    margin-left: initial   !important;
    padding-left: initial  !important;
    padding-top: initial  !important;

}

._5vb_, ._5vb_ #contentCol {
background: none !important;
}
```

[image]